# You are to create a committee of $2$ men and $2$ women from a group of $8$ men and $8$ women. Each committee member will fill a role,…

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

You are to create a committee of $2$ men and $2$ women from a group of $8$ men and $8$ women.

Each committee member will fill a role; president, vice president, secretary, and treasurer.

How many unique committees could be formed?

I don't exactly know how to solve this although I enumerated the possibilities with a script to count the ones that would be unique.

I wanted to see if the number I got was correct, and maybe see how I would get it without a script.

It seems way to high:  $18816$ unique committees.  Thanks.

Thanks for your time,
Julian

Comment: I get $\binom 82=28$ ways to choose the two men.  Same number of ways to choose the two women.  $4!$ ways to permute your list. Hence $\binom 82 \binom 82 4! = 28^*28^*24=18816$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${8 \choose 2} \times{8 \choose 2}\times 4! = \left(\frac{8!}{2!6!}\right)^2 4! = 28^2 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 18,816$

In English: (number of ways of choosing 2 men from 8 men) times (number of ways of choosing 2 women from 8 women) times (4 choices of president) times (3 choices of vice president once the president has been chosen) times (2 choices of secretary once the other two positions have been filled) times (only 1 choice of treasurer).